# PHP and MySQL. Include Connect-DB out of a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I was just organizing one of my codes and notice that leaving the connect-mydb.php out of a function, it doesnt work. 
I always thought the include would be loaded prior to any of the functions.

connect-mydb.php

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$db = 'mydb';
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
?>
```

testdb_out.php (doesnt work)

```
<?php
include 'connect-mydb.php';

function UpdateDB() {
echo "working\n";
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 'aloha' WHERE id = '1'";
$saved = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
if ($saved) {
  echo 'success';
}else{
  echo 'failed';
}
}
UpdateDB();
?>
```

testdb_within.php (works)

```
<?php
function UpdateDB() {
include 'connect-mydb.php';

$query = "UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 'aloha' WHERE id = '1'";
$saved = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
if ($saved) {
  echo 'success';
}else{
  echo 'failed';
}
}

UpdateDB();
?>
```

In testdb_out, shouldnt the include be loaded prior to the function? That works in other programming languages.

Comment: If it is outside of function then it is a global variable, and globals are not present by default inside of function scope. Use `global $mysqli;` inside function.

Comment: great guys thank you for the prompt replies!!! I though include was by default global and considered in functions.